# How do I properly determine the relationships in Entity Framework from metadata classes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, metadata

I'm currently using a package that collects API data ([Crayon API NuGet Package](https://github.com/CrayonGroup/crayon-api-sdk)), however, I'm struggling to implement this through Entity Framework. I am pulling Data from Crayon and I want to store it into a database, the code is fine, it's just the entity framework part that isn't working as I want it to. When I run the migrations I get this error :

*"Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'BillingStatement.TotalSalesPrice' of type 'Price'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."*

So by the looks of this error I need to configure the relationships, but I'm not sure how to do that through metadata, since the API data and classes are set in the package (metadata). But here is the Entity Framework model I'm using.

```
public class CrayonDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionString = @"myserver";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<BillingStatement> BillingStatements { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<AddressData>().HasNoKey();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Price>().HasNoKey();
        }
    }
```

Here is the BillingStatement class from the metadata that it's using.

```
namespace Crayon.Api.Sdk.Domain.Csp
{
    public class BillingStatement
    {
        public BillingStatement();

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Price TotalSalesPrice { get; set; }
        public ObjectReference InvoiceProfile { get; set; }
        public ObjectReference Organization { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
        public ProvisionType ProvisionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now here are the referenced classes from the previously shown billing statement class.

```
public class Price
{
    public Price();

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectReference
{
    public ObjectReference();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum ProvisionType
{
    None = 0,
    Seat = 1,
    Usage = 2,
    OneTime = 3,
    Crayon = 4,
    AzureMarketplace = 5
}
```

I'm aware that when Normalization is involved it starts to become a lot more complicated. What would I do with this? How would I configure the relationships? Is there any good source material that helps with metadata classes where I can scaffold the tables and store the data as intended?

Any help here would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make some database design decisions to get this to work.  For that particular one Price should probably be configured as an [Owned Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#:%7E:text=%20Owned%20Entity%20Types%20%201%20Explicit%20configuration.,types%20use%20OwnsMany%20in%20OnModelCreating.%20Owned...%20More%20) like this:

```
public class BillingStatement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Price TotalSalesPrice { get; set; }
    public ObjectReference InvoiceProfile { get; set; }
    public ObjectReference Organization { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
    public ProvisionType ProvisionType { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectReference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public enum ProvisionType
{
    None = 0,
    Seat = 1,
    Usage = 2,
    OneTime = 3,
    Crayon = 4,
    AzureMarketplace = 5
}

public class Price
{

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
public class Db : DbContext
{

    public Db() : base()
    {

    }

    private static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter((category, level) =>
           category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
           && level == LogLevel.Debug).AddConsole();
    });

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var constr = "Server=localhost; database=efcore5test; integrated security = true; TrustServerCertificate=true";

        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                      .UseSqlServer(constr, o => o.UseRelationalNulls());


        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BillingStatement>().OwnsOne<Price>( s => s.TotalSalesPrice);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BillingStatement>().OwnsOne<ObjectReference>(s => s.InvoiceProfile);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BillingStatement>().OwnsOne<ObjectReference>(s => s.Organization);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Which will create a table like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE [BillingStatement] (
      [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      [TotalSalesPrice_Value] decimal(18,2) NULL,
      [TotalSalesPrice_CurrencyCode] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [InvoiceProfile_Id] int NULL,
      [InvoiceProfile_Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Organization_Id] int NULL,
      [Organization_Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [StartDate] datetimeoffset NOT NULL,
      [EndDate] datetimeoffset NOT NULL,
      [ProvisionType] int NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_BillingStatement] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
  );
```

You'll might also want to replace the `ObjectReference` objects with proper navigation properties to the target objects, as that appears to be an artifact of the API implementation that you might not want in your database.

Comment: Hey David, Thank you for your input, I've tried doing that, the only issue is I get this error instead: "The navigation 'TotalSalesPrice' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'Price'. Navigations can only target entity types with keys.", even though I set it HasNoKey() in the model builder

Comment: The only thing is I can't change the values since it's metadata and the data is in a NuGet package. So the classes that you've edited I can't physically edit.

Comment: https://github.com/CrayonGroup/crayon-api-sdk

There from this

Comment: You can do this without modifying the source types using the Fluent API.  See updated answer.